# How to sort on elastic search query based on a matching property?

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "type": "admin",
            "date": "2016-03-02T12:34:00+08:00",
            "status": "2"
        },
        {
            "type": "staff",
            "date": "2016-03-02T12:34:00+08:00",
            "status": "2"
        } 
    ],
    "features": "1 2 3 4 5"
}
```

Lets say I have above Elasticsearch document structure. I want get all the documents on that index but those who has feature `3` should be at the top/begging of the search result. I went through Elasticsearch documentation but I couldn't figure out how to do it. Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: What's the mapping for the `features` field?

Comment: string @AndreiStefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "features": "3"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This is working just fine. Can you share some links/tutorial from where I can learn myself to write this type queries ? Thanks.